# Cascade delete not working for Ektorp (a Java persistence API for couchdb)

Tags: java, couchdb

We are stuck with cascading delete when using ektorp for couchDb. Ours is a complex object. We are able to save different documents for all the children in the object tree but delete just deletes the parent document and not the associated documents. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the @DocumentReferences annotation?

Make sure you have set cascade = CascadeType.DELETE

Read more here http://ektorp.org/reference_documentation.html#d99e369

Comment: Henrik,
This problem is occurring even after using @documentreferences and CascadeType.Delete.

Comment: If you delete the parent, the children will not be deleted regardless of the setting. It is a limitation which is actually mentioned in the reference docs.